# error while loading shared libraries: libtinyxml.so.2.6.2: cannot

Tags: ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, since the past several days I have been having issues with libtinyxml I guess. This is what happens:

```
iitrobotics@iitrobotics-Satellite-T135:~$ rosrun rviz rviz
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization/rviz/bin/rviz: error while loading shared libraries: libtinyxml.so.2.6.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure how to correct this. Thanks for any help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11629/error-while-loading-shared-libraries:-libtinyxml.so.2.6.2:-cannot/) by [marin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1254/marin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2011-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS repository used to contain a backported libtinyxml2.6.2 for Natty, but it has been removed for some reason, although the built packages still need it. You can download it from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tinyxml/. You need the libtinyxml2.6.2_2.6.2-1_*.deb file for your architecture (i386 or amd64).

I assumed this was a temporary problem. Is there going to be an official fix, or should I open a ticket?

---

Originally posted by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) with karma: 1951 on 2011-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2011-10-25**:
It's fixed now. Thanks for the swift update!

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-10-25**:
The debs have been fixed on Maverick and Natty to use the built in version.  An update and upgrade should fix it.

**Comment by [marin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1254/marin/) on 2011-10-24**:
Worked great. Thanks for submitting the ticket

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2011-10-23**:
https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5223

**Comment by [marin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1254/marin/) on 2011-10-22**:
thanks for the reply i will try what you suggested in the morning. Thanks!

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-10-22**:
We realized we had the backport accidentally in our repo and removed it. The latest debs in the repo should have been rebuilt to use the native tinyxml version, if that's not true please do ticket it.